# Empty output using GAWK on Mac OSX Maverick

Tags: unix, gawk

I have tab-separated files (sorry I don't know how to format it, should not be space, but tab).

```
""  "logFC" "logCPM"    "LR"    "PValue"    "FDR"
"A1BG"  -0.2    -1.5    5.3 0.0 0.1
```

Mark that columns- and rows- names have "" around them, the values have not. And again, its tab-separated.

My code is:

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv | gawk 'NR==1 {if ($1=="something" || $1=="something2") print $1,$2,$4,;}' >  test1.txt
```

"test1.txt" is however empty and I don't know why..

So if I ran:

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv | gawk 'NR==1 {if ($1=="A1BG") print $1,$2,$4,;}' >  A1BG.txt
```

I want A1BG.txt to look like:

```
""  ""  "logFC" "LR"
file1.csv "A1BG"    -0.2 5.3
file2.csv "A1BG"    y x
```

Comment: Thanks for editing.. Trying to figure out how you did that..

Comment: When you ask a question, there's an orange question mark you can click on for formatting help.  There are also a bunch of useful icons at the top of the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you hoping to accomplish with `NR==1` in your awk action?  That means your action will only execute for the first line of your input.  So regardless of how many lines of input you feed to awk, that action will (a) only run once, and (b) may not output anything, unless the first line happens to match `something` or `something2`.

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but maybe this will help:

```
gawk '
  NR==1 {print}
  $1 == "something" || $1 == "something2" {print FILENAME, $1,$2,$4}
' file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv >  test1.txt
```

This will run for every line, instead of just the first one.  If the first field is `something` or `something2`, it will print out fields 1, 2, and 4.

**UPDATE**: I've modified this to print the first line of the input.

Comment: NR==1 is supposed to print out the first row (column names).

Comment: In that position, `NR==1` is a *condition* -- "IF the value of `NR` == 1, then do the following aciton".  You only have one action in your file.

Comment: See my update if you want to print the first line in addition to columns 1,2, and 4 of matching lines.

Comment: Then `$1` isn't matching, and you need to figure out why.  I'll give you a hint: in your sample data above, the value of field 1 in the second line is not `A1BG`.  If you want to check for "contains" instead of "equal to", you would need to change the condition.

Comment: Should it be '$1 ~ /A1BG/'? But the problem with this one is that I get everything containing A1BG i.e. A1BGa, A1BGb, A1BGc etc. I want only exact A1BG.

Comment: Your field contains quotation marks.  So, `$1 == "\"A1BG\"" {...}`.

Comment: Thats the one yes! I been searching a lot to find out how to handle the "". Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Final question, how can I print if it comes from "file1.csv" or "file2.csv"?

Comment: Stop using `cat` so that `awk` knows the name of the input files, and then you can use the `FILENAME` variable.  See my update for an example, and see [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_6.html) for more information.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind... (I tried that one.. But it only outputs "-", maybe because of "cat"?)